How to implement the Builder pattern in Delphi using records without creating copies?
I am trying to implement the Builder design pattern in Delphi using records. My goal is to allow chaining of methods, similar to how it’s done in Kotlin, Java, or Swift. For example:
val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Builder Example")
    .setMessage("This is a builder pattern example")
    .create()

In Delphi, I wrote the following code using a record:
type
  TAlertDialogBuilder = record
  private
    FTitle: string;
    FMessage: string;
  public
    function SetTitle(const ATitle: string): TAlertDialogBuilder;
    function SetMessage(const AMessage: string): TAlertDialogBuilder;
    procedure CreateAndShow;
  end;

implementation

function TAlertDialogBuilder.SetTitle(const ATitle: string): TAlertDialogBuilder;
begin
  FTitle := ATitle;
  Result := Self; // Creates a copy
end;

function TAlertDialogBuilder.SetMessage(const AMessage: string): TAlertDialogBuilder;
begin
  FMessage := AMessage;
  Result := Self; // Creates a copy
end;

procedure TAlertDialogBuilder.CreateAndShow;
begin
  ShowMessage(Format('Title: %s%sMessage: %s', [FTitle, sLineBreak, FMessage]));
end;

I use it like this:
procedure ShowDialogExample;
begin
  TAlertDialogBuilder.Create
    .SetTitle('Builder Example')
    .SetMessage('This is a builder pattern example')
    .CreateAndShow;
end;

The Problem:
Since records are value types in Delphi, returning Self in methods like SetTitle and SetMessage results in a copy of the record. This is not efficient, especially if the record has many fields or large data.
What I’ve Tried:

Returning a Pointer to the Record: I modified the methods to return a pointer to the record (PAlertDialogBuilder) instead of Self. While this avoids copies, it makes chaining less intuitive because I need to dereference the pointer with ^ for subsequent calls.

Using absolute: I considered using the absolute keyword to avoid copies, but I couldn’t figure out a way to make it work for chaining method calls.

Switching to Classes: I know classes avoid this issue because they are reference types, but I’d prefer to stick with records if possible for their lightweight nature and value semantics.


My Question:
How can I implement the Builder pattern in Delphi using records while avoiding unnecessary copies? Is there a way to use absolute or another approach to achieve this efficiently?


I need to dereference the pointer with ^ for subsequent calls.

No, you don't. Dereferencing a pointer with ^ is optional. This is documented:
Using Extended Syntax with Pointers

The {$EXTENDED} compiler directive affects the use of the caret (^). When {$X+} is in effect (the default), you can omit the caret when referencing pointers. The caret is still required when declaring a pointer and for resolving the ambiguity when a pointer points to another pointer. For more information, see Extended syntax (Delphi).
With extended syntax enabled, you can omit the caret when referring to a pointer, as in the following example:
{$X+}
 type
   PMyRec = ^TMyRec;
   TMyRec = record
     Data: Integer;
   end;

 var
   MyRec: PMyRec;

 begin
   New(MyRec);
   MyRec.Data := 42;  {#1}
 end.

When extended syntax is not enabled, the line marked {#1} would typically be expressed as:
 MyRec^.Data := 42;




Is there... another approach to achieve this efficiently?

One option would be to change the Builder itself to be an interfaced class. That way, you pass around references, and you avoid copies and leaks.
For example:
type
  IAlertDialogBuilderIntf = interface
    function SetTitle(const ATitle: string): IAlertDialogBuilderIntf;
    function SetMessage(const AMessage: string): IAlertDialogBuilderIntf;
    procedure CreateAndShow;
  end;

  TAlertDialogBuilderImpl = class(TInterfacedObject, IAlertDialogBuilderIntf)
  private
    FTitle: string;
    FMessage: string;
  public
    function SetTitle(const ATitle: string): IAlertDialogBuilderIntf;
    function SetMessage(const AMessage: string): IAlertDialogBuilderIntf;
    procedure CreateAndShow;
  end;

  TAlertDialog = class
    ...
    function Builder(params): IAlertDialogBuilderIntf;
    ...
  end;

implementation

function TAlertDialogBuilderImpl.SetTitle(const ATitle: string): IAlertDialogBuilderIntf;
begin
  FTitle := ATitle;
  Result := Self;
end;

function TAlertDialogBuilderImpl.SetMessage(const AMessage: string): IAlertDialogBuilderIntf;
begin
  FMessage := AMessage;
  Result := Self;
end;

procedure TAlertDialogBuilderImpl.CreateAndShow;
begin
  ShowMessage(Format('Title: %s%sMessage: %s', [FTitle, sLineBreak, FMessage]));
end;

function TAlertDialog.Builder(params): IAlertDialogBuilderIntf;
begin
  Result := TAlertDialogBuilderImp.Create as IAlertDialogBuilderIntf;
end;


Wooow +100 Remy didn't know about {$EXTENDED}. I do not want to use Interface,it's add overhead that i do not want, i want the most efficient solution as possible

If you plan to implement the Builder using pointers to records, I'm thinking you could just as well use classes? It would involve less magic, and be essentially the same thing. The main reason to use records instead of classes it to get the passing by value/automatic copying. If you don't need that (and even want to specifically avoid that), then classes are simpler.

@zeus The only other option I can think of would be to move the data fields into a record/class that is allocated dynamically in Builder(), and then have your chaining pass around lightweight records as you want, where they hold a pointer to that data. But then you have the lifetime issue to deal with, which interfaces would handle nicely for you.

@MatthiasB probleme of class is that we need to create it and this is a little time consuming (allocating memory, etc.) this why i prefer to stay with record. pointer to a record with {$EXTENDED} fit perfectly my need for performance and easy to use

@zeus: Just remember that an inline, type inferred variable declaration assigned to such a fluent interface will then get assigned (and typed as) a POINTER and not the record itself. That may be what you want, but just beware.
